# How to get contacts from Azure Ad graph api

Tags: c#, active-directory, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to get contacts list using Azure AD Graph API but don't know how to give permission for application to read contacts. Azure AD Graph API provides operation for these objects only

"Application,
Device,
Directory,
Domain,
Member,
Policy"

Please let me know how to give permissions for app to read contacts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, microsoft graph api has already replace the azure ad graph(Now Microsoft recommends microsoft graph over azure ad graph). So you can use the microsoft graph api([List contacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-contacts?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)).

You just need to go to your app in azure ad and click "API permissions" button and then follow the steps below:
[image]

Then add the permissions which mentioned in the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-contacts?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to your application.
[image]

After that, we also need to click the button "Grant admin consent for * ".
[image]

Now you can request the access token from your app and use the token to request the graph api.

**Update:**

If you want to request the azure ad graph api, you just need to add the `Directory.Read.All` permission. If use "password" as `grant_type`, please add the `Directory.Read.All` under "Delegated permissions". If use "client_credentials" as `grant_type`, please add the `Directory.Read.All` under "Application permissions".
[image]

After that, you can request the azure ad graph api get contacts successfully.

Comment: Thanks ! but I need to get contact list from azure ad graph api

Comment: Hi @user12679706, I have updated my answer, please check.

Comment: Hi @user12679706 May I know if your problem was solved ? If the solution works, could you please mark my answer as "accepted", thanks~